# Looping in an oracle table based on partitions

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I am creating a Query which is taking data from multiple other databases through DBlinks.

One of the table "ord" in a Query is immensely large , say more than 50 million rows.

Now, I want to create query and I want to traverse the data and retrieve the required data  based on Partitions defined in t1.

i.e if ord has 50 partitions in it with 1 million records each, I want to run my whole query on first partition get the result ,then move to 2nd, 3rd and so on. . upto last partition.

How can I do that?

Please consider the Sample Query where from local DB I am accessing all the remote DBs using DB links.

This Query list all the orders which are active.

```
Select ord.order_no,
ord.customer_id,
ord.order_date,
cust.customer_id,
cust.cust_name,
adr.street,
adr.city,
adr.state,
ship.ship_addr_street,
ship.ship_addr_city,
ship.ship_addr_state,
ship.ship_date
from order ord@ordDB
inner join customer@custDB cust on cust.customer_id = ord.customer_id
inner join address@adrDB adr on adr.address_id = cust.address_id
inner join shipment@shipDB ship on ship.shipment_id = ord.shipment_id
where ord.active = 'true';
```

Now there is a feild "partition_key" defined in this table, and each key is associated with say 1 million rows and I want to restructure the query so that at one time we take one partition from Order and run this whole query on that partition and move to next partition until table is not completed.

Please help me to create sample query.

Comment: Do you mean querying a single specific partition [like this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51147); or are you asking how to supply the partition name dynamically? How does the 'move to next' part work? And why do you want to do this if you're going to be querying all partitions anyway - won't this be less efficient, as it has to query all the other tables multiple times?

Comment: In general it does not matter if you select a remote DB or the local one. The behaviour should be the same.

Comment: Are you referring to "partitions" in the Oracle database sense, where a "partition" is a sub-piece of a table that can be used to improve query time, spread a single table's data across multiple tablespaces, etc, or is "partition" in this case a term for the logical data in your table? It appears to me you mean the latter (that "partition", in this case, means "a subset of my data" and is not related to physical table structure).  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you want to add: and ord.partition_key = "P1" , get the results, do something with the results, and then move on to "P2"?  If thats the case, then wrap this SQL in pl/sql and loop through the partition keys. (unless I misunderstand what you want ;)

Comment: My query is taking large time to execute : "hours". My **ORDER** table is partitioned based on **PARTITION_KEY** AND **PARTITION_DATE**. 

AND I want to **Dynamically** pass the partition KEYs to the query and then based on that I want to get the results of whole query and again perform this same operation for next partition key in a loop.

How can I do that using PL/SQL?

Comment: Also, **PARTITION_KEY** is like {1543,3244,5435,345...}
**The PARTITION_KEY is calculated based on the order_no. That is, a formula is used which converts the order_no string into a number. This formula is always used, even when the order_no is already a number. The formula is defined on the Oracle level and Java-code level. On the Oracle level, it can be used in conversion scripts.**

So, I have a partition_date say 1jan2000 and I want to use it with different Partition Keys which matches the combination and then based on this condition I want to run the query. :)

Comment: It appears you want to do something like `SELECT DISTINCT PARTITION_KEY FROM ORDER WHERE PARTITION_DATE = TO_DATE('01-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` to get back the PARTITION_KEY values used on that date, and then you want to `SELECT * FROM ORDER WHERE PARTITION_KEY = whatever AND PARTITION_DATE = TO_DATE('01-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes! Bob, Its Correct. and I want to iterate the whole Query based on partition numbers. i.e. if `SELECT DISTINCT PARTITION_KEY FROM ORDER WHERE PARTITION_DATE = TO_DATE('01-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` returns 5 different values, then I want to run query in loop on all these values on by one. :)

Comment: The most reliable way to find all of the partitions would be to go to the data dictionary and parse out the `high_value` contents.